# Why DatePickerDialog is using spinner view after updating to android 7.0

Tags: calendar, android-7.0-nougat, datepickerdialog

I have an Honor V8 that has just updated to android 7.0
But now the DatePickerDialog in my app no longer shows a calendar, just spinners.
[image]

When I test in a emulator with android 7.0, it shows again the calendar.
[image]

I'm using this code to call the DatePickerDialog:

```
public static void OpenCalendarioDialog(Activity activity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener, int year, int month, int day) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat( activity.getApplicationContext());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String title = dateFormat.format(GetTimeDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
    dialog.setTitle(title);

    dialog.show();
}
```

So how I can make sure my DatePickerDialog will always use calendar view?
I'm not interested using a third party library

Comment: "So how I can make sure my DatePickerDialog will always use calendar view?" -- if Huawei changed the way `DatePickerDialog` works, perhaps you can't. Beyond that, please provide a [mcve] showing how you are setting up the `DatePickerDialog` and requesting the calendar.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare! Just added my code. Thank you

Comment: That looks fairly normal, which means that I have to assume that Huawei messed with `DatePickerDialog`, or possibly with `CalendarView`. Try tossing a `CalendarView` into a layout somewhere and see if it comes up OK on the Huawei. If that works, you can create your own dialog that wraps a `CalendarView`. If the `CalendarView` widget itself is broken, see if there is some theme setting that you can perhaps set to try to force the `CalendarView` to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is so simple I feel ashamed.

I just had to raise the targetSdkVersion to 24 because of the android 7.0

That reminds me when something is not working after an update this is the first thing I should check.

Edit: 
I was wrong! Raising the targetSdkversion didn't solve the problem.
Instead, I had to add a DatePicker in a AlertDialog.
After the samsung lollipop issue, now this? Android is such a mess!!

Comment: I have the same problem, in a Huawei device too, and updated to targetSdkVersion 25 and it is still showing the "wrong" DatePickerDialog

Comment: @allo86 I also have the same problem on Huawei device and targetSdkVersion 25, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @IljaS. no, I haven't :(

Comment: Same issue here with Huawei Honor 8 Lite

Comment: Did anyone fix it  ?